# Size flexbox div to the size of the content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox that looks like so and I'm trying to remove all the extra space at the end of the content.

[image]

I would like it to be sized something like below where the width is sized to fit the content inside and not wider than it needs to be.

[image]

I also want it to have the property where the width will grow as it needs to in order to fit the content inside and then wrap to the next line when required.

[image]

And of course, I would like the child elements to be reasonably sized to fit their content (i.e. labels, selects, etc. are wide enough to display their content.

Here is a simple jsfiddle of what I have now https://jsfiddle.net/6xLr9qfu/1/. The css is also shown below:

```
#inner {
  background: lightskyblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#inner > * {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `display:inline-block;` on `#app`, this will keep the content to their width and expand their width when the data increased.

you can check by removing the content and you can see the difference.

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/w5r3ka07/2/) if you want to play around.

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#inner {
  background: lightskyblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#inner>* {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div id="inner">
    <label>Some text</label>
    <select id="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <select id="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <select id="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <select id="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <select id="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <select id="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <select id="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to prevent the flex element from taking up the full width, use 
`display: inline-flex;` and it will behave like a `<span>` element, not a block one, but with flex's capabilities.

```css
#inner {
  background: lightskyblue;
  border-radius: 10px;

  display: inline-flex; 

  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```